# How can I take 2 numbers from "form" and add them so I can output the result

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new at JavaScript and I really can't get this to work fully. I have a form that takes 2 numbers and a button that runs a function which is supposed to add that 2 numbers and display them, but it only displays them as plain text (for example I submit 5 and 23 it would display it as "523").

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="num1">First number:</label>
      <input type="number" id="num1" name="num2">
      <br>
      <label for="num2">Second number:</label>
      <input type="number" id="num2" name="num2">
      <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="addNums()">Calculate</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function addNums()
{
    let num1 = document.querySelector("#num1").value;
    let num2 = document.querySelector("#num2").value;
    document.write(num1 + num2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's concatenating your num1 and num2 variables as strings. You'll need to convert it into a number, using something like [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), like so:

```
let num1 = Number(document.querySelector("#num1").value);
let num2 = Number(document.querySelector("#num2").value);
document.write(num1 + num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of num1 and num2 are of type string and the `+` sign is concatenating the values instead of adding them, you can solve the issue by casting the values with `parseInt` function.

here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wq7tjo04/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addNums()
{
    let num1 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#num1").value);
    let num2 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#num2").value);
    document.write(num1 + num2);
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="num1">First number:</label>
      <input type="number" id="num1" name="num2">
      <br>
      <label for="num2">Second number:</label>
      <input type="number" id="num2" name="num2">
      <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="addNums()">Calculate</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

You should convert `string` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

change your function to :

```
function addNums() {
  let num1 = document.querySelector("#num1").value;
  let num2 = document.querySelector("#num2").value;
  document.write(+num1 + +num2);
}
```

also, change your first input name num2 to num1 if you planning to post it through the form.

Comment: Use parseInt : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt =>  document.write(parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)); or parseFloat : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseFloat